# Android - I want Navigation button and viewpager do the same function

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am working in project that contain framelayout display fragments by navigation button next , back and I provide it method below in my code till now every thing works great

here is why I am here , I need make the same function done with navigation button done with swipe button , I add viewpager and pass all fragment to adapter but it give me different view overlapping

```
Fragment mFragmentsList[] = new Fragment[]{new Slide2Frag() , .... new Slide23Frag()};

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // here is what I need to add viewpager 
        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragmentsList);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        DisplayFragment(count);


    }

// display fragment method

 private void DisplayFragment(int display) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (display) {
            case 2:
                fragment = new Slide2Frag();
                break;

                }

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            mTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            } 


 private void NextMethod() {
        if (count < 23) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 2;
        }
        DisplayFragment(count);
    }

    private void backMethod() {
        if (count > 2) {
            count--;
        } else {
            count = 23;
        }
        DisplayFragment(count);
    }
```

my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="219dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="219dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/close" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/aciloc" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_btn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/leadingppi"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    </RelativeLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_layout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout" >
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left_nav"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/left_back"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ac20"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="Aciloc 20mg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ac40"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="Aciloc 40mg" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="PROFILE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/indications"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="INDICATIONS &amp; DOSAGE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pack"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="UNIQUE PACK" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_nav"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/right_back"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is image explain [image]